# How to properly format text retrieved from a website?

Tags: php, android, textview, format, html

I'm building an application for a company that, unfortunately, has a very poorly designed website. Most of the HTML tags are wrongly and sometimes randomly placed, there is excessive use of no-break-spaces, p tags are randomly assigned, they don't follow any rule and so on...

I'm retrieving data from their website by using a crawler and then feeding the resulted strings to my application through my own web-service. The problem is that once displaying it into the android textview, the text is formatted all wrong, spread and uneven, very dissorderly.

Also, worth mentioning that I can not suggest to the company for various reasons to modify their website...

I've tried

```
String text = Html.fromHtml(myString).toString();
```

and other variations, I've even tried formatting it manually but it's been a pain.

My question is:

Is there an easy, elegant way to re-format all this text, either with PHP on my web-service or with Java, directly in my Android application?

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to answer...

Comment: Wouldn't stripping all HTML tags help?

Comment: That's what I tried with the above-mentioned fragment of code. Didn't help...I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. P.S. Nice to see another Romanian around here, at 3:30 in the morning :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but I managed to get the best results by stripping some tags according to what I needed with php (that was really easy to do) and then displaying the retrieved strings into formatted WebViews.

As I said, probably not the most elegant solution but in this case it worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) with PHP to clean up the code if you're keeping it in place. Otherwise stripping the HTML would probably make working with it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would so: no, there is no easy, elegant way. HTML combines data and visual representation, they are inherently linked. To understand the data you must look at the tags. Tags like `<h1>` and `<a>` carry meaning.

If the HTML is structured enough to break it down into meaningful blocks: header, body and unrelated/unimportant stuff. Then you could apply restyling principles to those. A simple solution is to just strip all the tags, get only the textNodes and stitch them together. If the HTML is exceptionally poorly formatted you might get sentences that are out of order, but if the HTML isn't too contrived I expect this approach should work.

To give you an indication of the complexity involved: You could have `<span>`s that have styling applied to them, for instance `display: block`. This changes the way the span is displayed, from inline to block, so it behaves more like a `<div>` would. This means that each `<span>` will likely be on it's own line, it will seem to force a line break. Detecting these situations isn't impossible but it is quite complex. Who knows what happens when you've got list elements, tables or even floating elements; they might be completely out of order.

Comment: I tried stripping the tags directly in my app with what code I mentioned above. I'm probably doing something wrong, because it didn't help. I'll try stripping the tags through PHP as well, but I was hoping to keep the text looking as close to the original website as possible